# How can I free memory allocated by Rust code exposed in WebAssembly?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I have a web application written in Rust and wasm-bindgen that needs to store state. The state is stored like this:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref ID_TO_DATA: Mutex<HashMap<u32, Data>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

pub struct Data {
    pub coder_id: u16,
    pub bools: Vec<bool>,
    pub ints: Vec<i32>,
    pub strings: Vec<String>,
}
```

I attempted the following to remove the data and free the memory, and the data is removed from the `HashMap` and no errors are reported:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn remove_data(id: u32) {
    match ID_TO_DATA.lock().unwrap().remove(&id) {
        Some(data) => {
            std::mem::drop(data);
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

However, the memory used by the browser tab never drops (using Chrome 67). I used Windows' Task Manager and watched the memory grow to almost 2GB for the relevant process/tab, and then after my program removed all the entries, I waited a minute and the memory was still at almost 2GB.

I also tried the following, but got this error: `RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn remove_data(id: u32) {
    match ID_TO_DATA.lock().unwrap().remove(&id) {
        Some(mut data) => {
            unsafe {
                std::ptr::drop_in_place(&mut data);
            }
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

How can I successfully free this memory?

Comment: Can you show us how you measured memory usage in the browser? You might also want to know [how `std::mem::drop` is implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/mem.rs#L795), so as to avoid misusage.

Comment: As E_net4 alludes, your `remove_data` method can be written as `ID_TO_DATA.lock().unwrap().remove(&id);`. No calls to `drop`, no `match`.

Comment: In general (not just in Rust), freed memory is not restored to the operating system, but to the program's allocator. See, e.g., [Python memory releasing very slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690301/python-memory-releasing-very-slowly), [Linux Allocator Does Not Release Small Chunks of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943907/linux-allocator-does-not-release-small-chunks-of-memory), and [In Perl, how can I release memory to the operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242832/in-perl-how-can-i-release-memory-to-the-operating-system)

Comment: Thanks to @trentcl, I thought I'd try it again with multiple cycles of adding / removing data, and although the browser memory never drops significantly, it doesn't keep growing, so I can only assume the memory is being reused by WebAssembly.  This is sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[WebAssembly does not offer any instructions to deallocate memory](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html#memory-instructions), there is only the ability to increase the allocated size. Practically speaking, this means that the peak memory usage of your WebAssembly application is also the **permanent** memory usage.

For a given problem, it may be possible to tweak your algorithm to reduce the peak amount of memory.

I don't have the knowledge or ability to test this, but one out-of-the-box idea would be to try and have multiple WebAssembly runtimes distinct from each other. You could chew up a lot of memory in one to compute a relatively small result, serialize that result outside of the WASM runtime, then throw it away and spin up a new one. This is likely only to be useful in certain specific problem domains.

---

In the future, memory resizing may be **re**-added to WebAssembly. It was explicitly removed before the MVP release:

> After the MVP, we are moving to things that diverge and cannot be polyfilled, and memory resizing makes more sense to add at that point in time.

- [Remove memory resizing from the MVP (294)](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/294)
- [Only allow memory growth in MVP (389)](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/pull/389)

Thanks to [alexcrichton](https://discordapp.com/channels/442252698964721669/443151097398296587/472096547635462156) and [steveklabnik](https://discordapp.com/channels/442252698964721669/443151097398296587/472096596725858314) for answering this question in the Rust Discord.